Find a number that will have $\gcd(n, m)^2 = \text {lcm}(n, m)$ with other 20 numbers at least
For a natural number $n$ we define a function $f(n)$ = number of the natural numbers $m$ such that $\gcd(n, m)^2 = \text {lcm}(n, m)$.
The task is to find a minimal number n such that $f(n) > 20$.
I don't understand how to solve in analytically and my code works like infinitely. Maybe you know some helping theorem or formula that will allow me calculate it.

I suggest: write out both sides in terms of the prime factorization of $n, m$.

You should use MathJax also in the title.

Suppose we had a "good" pair $(n,m)$.  Write $n=\prod p_i^{n_i}$ and $m=\prod p_i^{m_i}$ for the two prime factorizations.
Then your condition is equivalent to $$2\min (n_i, m_i)=\max (n_i, m_i)\quad \forall i$$
As the gcd is obtained by taking the mins, and the lcm is obtained by taking the max.
Note that there is no trouble producing good pairs, as $(p,p^2)$ is a good pair for any prime $p$.
Indeed, if $n$ is specified, then we can produce $m$ just by "choosing" whether, for a given $i$, the max is in $n$ or $m$.  Of course, if the max is in $n$ then we need the exponent of $p_i$ to be even.  If there are $k$ distinct primes in the factorization, that means $2^k$ choices.  We want $2^k>20$ so take $k=5$.
Thus we take $$\boxed {n=(2\times 3\times 5\times 7\times 11)^2}$$
All the exponents are even so we get $2^5$ choices for $m$...for each of the five primes just decide whether the exponent in $m$ should be $1$ or $4$.
I think the above discussion shows that this $n$ is minimal for the requirements, but that wasn't part of the question and I haven't thought the point through carefully.  Should be true though...after all, if $n$ has fewer than $5$ prime factors there can be no more than $4$ binary choices, so those are all out...and if one of the $n_i$ is odd then there is no choice to be made.

The problem is equivalent to $nm=\gcd(n,m)^3$. Set
$n=\prod_i p_i^{a_i}$ and
$m=\prod_i p_i^{b_i}$. Hence
$$
\prod_i p_i^{a_i+b_i}=\prod_i p_i^{3\min\{a_i,b_i\}}
$$
so
$a_i+b_i=3\min\{a_i,b_i\}$. If $a_i\geq b_i$, then $a_i=2b_i$. Hence $n=m^2$

Did you mean $\prod_i p_i^{3\min (a_i, b_i)}$?  After all, the gcd comes from the least exponent, not the greatest.

In any case, if $n=p$ and $m=p^2$ for a prime $p$ then we have $\gcd(m,n)^2=\text {lcm}(n,m)$

You right. I fixed it.

Well, you fixed one error.  But it obviously isn't true that the only good pairs are of the form $(n,\sqrt n)$.  All you know is that for each prime factor $p$  either $a_i=2b_1$ or $2a_i=b_i$.   For instance, if $p,q$ are distinct primes, then $(pq^2, p^2q)$ is a good pair.

Ok, it just a hint for the guy who wrote the question

If it's just a hint, you should make it obvious that it's just a hint (with further steps needed). Otherwise, an unsuspecting passerby might think that this is a complete solution that they can't understand.
